# Get likes of public photo on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get photo data (like likes) using the graph api, but it appears that some photos give me the data, but others return "Unsupported get request".
I'm only testing public pictures, using [GET /photo-id](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/photo).

[This](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=523919591041646) photo, for example, returns "Unsupported get request", as you can see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=523919591041646&version=v1.0).

Other photos do work, [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10152158321342014&version=v1.0) one, for example.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that one photo is created by a Page and the other one is created by a User. You can only get the User photos with a User Access Token, even if it´s a public one. For Page photos, you can use an App Access Token or a Page Access Token.

See those links for more information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Of course you also need to request the `user_photos` permission in the login process to get access to the User photos.

Btw, the `user_photos` permissions needs to get approved if you want to make it work for all Users. Without approval, it will only work for App Admins. See changelog and review guidelines:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Comment: what User Token? Hopefully a User Token from the User who posted the photo?

Comment: Indeed, a User Token from the User who posted the photo, without extended permissions.

Comment: and with the user_photos permission?

Comment: i updated my answer. will add some more info about permissions too.

Comment: I works now, using the user_photos permission. Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering... my app let's users post photos. I want to see how many likes every photo gets. Is this possible? Since I can't get the photo data without a User Access Token, I would think not?

Comment: you would need to use a user access token too. but they are not valid forever, so you cannot refresh the data without the user logging in once in a while...not a good idea imho.

Answer (score 0):

Error 100 indicates a syntax error in the URL you are posting to. Are you using a custom graph URL set? If so, double check it.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean exactly? I just took the ID that's in the photo-URL (https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=523919591041646), and pasted it in the Graph Api Explorer (and made sure I had an Access Token).

Comment: Can you try using the source URL?